# Is there a JMS API/Client that works with all AMQP brokers?

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, amqp, qpid

The JMS is the vendor neutral API to messaging in the Java space.  AMQP's mission is "to become the standard protocol for interoperability between all messaging middleware".  I'm looking for a JMS client implementation that is interoperable between AMQP vendors.  Specifically, it would be nice if it could talk to either RabbitMQ or Qpid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Qpid JMS client (which is, for the avoidance of effort, the same code as the OpenAMQ JMS client) encodes JMS in AMQP 0-9-1. I cannot speak for the quality of the client, but that should work for both Qpid Java edition and RabbitMQ.

It won't be an entirely lossless encoding, however -- there are some bits of API in JMS that don't carry across to AMQP. Qpid may have shims in place for those; RabbitMQ, by and large, doesn't.  I am thinking specifically of 'nolocal' and selectors. There are probably others.

(Actually it /kind of/ does selectors using AMQP header exchanges, but the results may not be what you expect from JMS)

There is an effort to create a JMS client that uses AMQP 1.0. But there are no Qpid nor RabbitMQ releases that support AMQP 1.0, which is after all really an entirely different protocol to 0-9-1 and other prior versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Apache Qpid client library (qpid-client-0.32-bin.tar.gz) with RabbitMQ (AMQP 0-9-1) recently and It worked very well.

If you want to connect to AMQP 1.0 Broker you should use this Qpid lib (apache-qpid-jms-0.1.0-bin.tar.gz)

Both libs can be downloaded from here:
http://qpid.apache.org/download.html

Comment: The accepted answer is old, now they do provide a 1.0 compatible client.

Answer (score 0):

Qpid itself has a JMS client.  I've never used it, but it is listed here under AMQP Client APIs

http://qpid.apache.org/